# Javascript SPA routing hashchange and back reloading

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm

So I have my spa and on a hashchange I'll load a new .html file into my

The thing is, when I hit the back button, I don't want to re-load by .html file because I want to keep my settings or items I clicked or changed in my viewmodel (I'm doing MVVM).
So below, if I hit the clickAbout funciton, it will go to the about page, but when I go back to the main list, all my settings are lost because it's re-loaded.  What the best way I should do this?  I guess I could use cookies, or maybe I just load the viewmodel on the masterpage.

```
        function clickAbout() {
            location.hash = "#about";
        }

            $(window).bind('hashchange', function (e) {
            var locationHashStr = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&')[0];
            $("#divContent").load("/Content/" + locationHashStr + ".html");
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (window.location.hash) {
                var locationHashStr = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&')[0]

                $("#divContent").load("/Content/" + locationHashStr + ".html");
            }
            else {

                location.hash = "#assetlist";

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pushstate.

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history.